# undefined reference to `pow' in yyparse

Tags: c, bison, yacc, pow

I have include math.h in my .yacc file and when I am trying to use the pow function in this part of the code it is giving me the above mentioned error

```
expression2:expression2 POWER_OP expression3  {/*keeping POWER_OP at highest precedence*/ $$ = pow($1,$3);}
```

and when I tried to put 2,3 or any constant value in the same part of code it is working fine

Comment: You need `-lm` in your compile options if you use the math library. Nothing to do with parsing.

Comment: Many of the [common mathematical functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math) are in a separate library that needs to be explicitly linked. That library is simply called `m`. I'm sure someone will come with a duplicate soon enough which is why I won't answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding -lm when compiling the files.
example:
gcc c.tab.c lex.yy.cc -lm